# Computable models of the ordinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, computability-theory, ordinal-numbers, ordinal-computability

It's known, for example in the answer to this question: [Is there a computable model of ZFC?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12426/is-there-a-computable-model-of-zfc) that ZFC has no computable model. My questions is: is there a model of ZFC for which the order relation on the class of ordinals is computable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this can happen: if $M$ is a countable $\omega$-model of ZF whose well-founded part has ordertype $\omega_1^{CK}$ (that is: has the shortest well-founded part possible for $\omega$-models), then $Ord^M$ as a linear order is just the **Harrison order**: $$\omega_1^{CK}+(\omega_1^{CK}\cdot\eta),$$ where $\eta$ is the ordertype of the rationals. This linear order does in fact have a computable copy, and is one of the basic examples/counterexamples in computable structure theory: a computable linear order which is illfounded but has no *hyperarithmetic* descending sequence (it has other nice properties too).

The key to seeing that this must be the ordertype is the following pair of observations:

- Given such an $M$ and an $\alpha\in Ord^M$, there must be an interval in $Ord^M$ beginning with $\alpha$ and isomorphic to $\omega_1^{CK}$.
- No interval in $Ord^M$ can be isomorphic to $\omega_1^{CK}+1$.

As to why such a model exists in the first place, this is trickier; depending how you phrase it, it's an application of either the **Gandy basis theorem** or the **Barwise(-Kreisel) compactness theorem**. Unfortunately, this doesn't have a one-line explanation.

Comment: Incidentally, an even sharper situation holds in arithmetic. By Tennenbaum, no nonstandard model of PA (say) is computable, but the ordertype of *any* countable nonstandard model of PA (or even vastly less) is exactly $\omega+\zeta\cdot\eta$ where $\zeta$ is the ordertype of the integers. Very little is directly coded into the ordertype, in either set theory or arithmetic.

Comment: How hard is it to construct an $\omega$-model of ZF whose well-founded part has order type $\omega_1^{CK}$? Does ZFC prove that the existence of such a model follows from the existence of any $\omega$-model?

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes: Gandy basis theorem. (In more detail: GBT says that - assuming there is an $\omega$-model of ZF at all - there is an $\omega$-model of ZF which is low for the hyperjump. But this model cannot have well-founded $\omega_1^{CK}$, or it would be within a couple *Turing* jumps of $\mathcal{O}$ and hence not low for the hyperjump. The model existence hypothesis is required to say that the relevant tree has a path, or that the relevant $\Sigma^1_1$ class is nonempty.)

Comment: I find the contrast with the uncountable model theoretic situation interesting. For uncountable $\lambda$, a model of PA is $\lambda$-saturated if and only if it is $\lambda$-saturated as a linear order. My understanding was that this is roughly true because you _can_ code 'enough' into the order type, in particular into cuts. I wonder if there are similar statements for ZF, ZFC, or ZF + Global Choice?

Comment: @JamesHanson Well, when I was talking about being unable to code directly into the ordertype, I was referring only to **countable** models; you're quite right that things are much more interesting higher up.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for the stated properties of the Harrison order?

Comment: @Wojowu I think this question may be useful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30633.